# OpenGL ES Performance Detective fails to collect evidence (Error: "contexts with different OpenGL ES API levels")

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, xcode4

I'm trying to investigate the OpenGL performance of an iOS app using the OpenGL ES Performance Detective. Upon opening a new "case" everything seems fine. But after clicking "Collect Evidence" the tool stalls for a few seconds, then gives me an error:

> This tool does not support contexts with different OpenGL ES API levels

I am using OpenGL ES 1, but I haven't read anything saying that the Detective only works on ES 2. Another interpretation of the error could be that it thinks I'm using multiple ES API levels, which seems to be untrue since the only reference to the API level is the standard:

```
context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1];
```

What does this error mean and what can I do to use this tool?